# How to avoid Application Not Responding dialog from showing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, web-services, handler

I'm using the method below to extract to convert XML into JSON.!

1. First I a pass the url for the api call of the xml and then extract
   the data and put it in String.
2. Then using this [Library](https://github.com/smart-fun/XmlToJson), I
   convert the xml into JSON Object.
3. Finally I use the json object data
   to get web data and populate my recyclerviews.

---

It works well, but sometimes it gives me ANR dialog..! any help?

```
  public static void getResponse(final String xmlLink, final Activity activity,
      final GetJSONRespone getjson) {

    Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
          url = new URL(xmlLink);

          in = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(
                  url.openStream(), "UTF-8")); 

          String inputLine;
          System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");  

          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(inputLine);
          }
          String urlContent = builder.toString();

          XmlToJson xmlToJson = new XmlToJson.Builder(urlContent).build();

          JSONObject response = xmlToJson.toJson();
          Log.i("response: ", response.toString());

          getjson.getJSON(response);


        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if (in != null) {
            try {
              in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Use asyntask for download data from API or use third party library like volly and Retrofit.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr

Comment: Try using Volley or RetroFit for JSON response, and to handle ANR please go through this -https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog appears when main thread of the application blocked for too long. So try to use ASYNCTASK to avoid this halt.

Comment: can you show me how, I didn't use it before!?

Comment: @SamZar Please look into the link https://xelsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/asynctask-implementation-using-callback-interface/